# Testcafe studio testcase saved on cloud by default?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

i am planning to use Testcafe studio and want to know the default location where all our test case store ? is it on Testcafe cloud ? if yes is there a way we can store the test case on our local box only don't want to store my test case on cloud because of security concern...please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Tests are stored on your computer. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401050/basic-guides/store-tests) for details.